# Couchbase warmup strategies

Tags: caching, memcached, couchbase

We have a memcached cluster running in production. Now we are replacing memcached with a Couchbase cluster as a persistent cache layer. The question is how to implement this cut-over and how to warm up Couchbase bucket. Obviously we can't simply switch over to the cold Couchbase since starting with old cache would bring the whole site down.

One option I was thinking is to warm up the Couchbase as a memcached node first. That means Couchbase is using the (non-persistent) memcached bucket, and getting the cache set/get traffic like any other memcached node. The good thing about it is there is minimum code changes (what's needed is configure the moxi proxy to take memcached traffic, and register that node as a memcached node). Later we will convert all memcached buckets to Couchbase. But not sure Couchbase supports the conversions between these two types of buckets.

The 2nd option is set up the persistent Couchbase bucket (as opposed to non-persistent memcached bucket) at the beginning. We change the production cache client to replicate all the traffic to both memcached and coucbase clusters. We monitor the Couchbase bucket and once the cache items reach certain size, we complete the cut-over. A small drawback is the extra complexity to change the cache client.

Thoughts?

EDIT on Aug 9, 2016

As I later found out, converting memcached bucket to couchbase bucket is not supported in Couchbase. So the first option is not feasible.

Finally we decide to set up the [Client-side (standalone) proxy](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Concepts/bp-deployment-strategies.html) in each application host. We do it incrementally from host to host to ramp up the cache traffic. That way the changes in the site is small enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want easy, less work, and proven to work well, do the following:

1. Set up a Moxi client on each application server.
2. Point Moxi to Couchbase bucket on the Couchbase cluster.
3. Change your web application servers to point at the local MOXI install.
4. For your next code revision start converting your code to using the Couchbase SDK instead of memcached.

Yes, there will be a time where things will not be hot in the cache, but it will not take long for Couchbase to get populated. This method is used all of the time to switch over. It is easy, nearly fool proof. One thing I have seen people do is try and copy things from their existing memcached servers over to Couchbase before cutting over, but what I am not sure of is how they new the key of each value in memcached.

Also note that Moxi is an interim step to easily get off of regular memcached and it is great, but for the long run, it is much better to switch to the SDK. The SDK has many more features than pure memcached.

Do not use the memcached buckets as they have none of the HA, persistence or whatever features of Couchbase.

Comment: Thanks, Kirk. This is what we finally decide to do. The application side moxi seems like a reasonable choice. For now we may even leave the setup like that and switch to SDK because switching cache clients in the code is too much pain.

Comment: Also, the same question with copying things from memcached to coucbbase before cutting over. That seems to add complexity rather than solving the problem.